# Интеграция моделей Python в Android Stuid

Tags: python, android, машинное-обучение, tensorflow

уважаемые форумчане.
Недавно стал заниматься машинным обучением.Сам я Android разработчик. Постиг меня интерес интегрировать обученные модели в Android. Нашел я на гите готовую к интеграции модель YOLO машиного зрения,получилось интегрировать ее в Android Studio с помощью NDK. Это был мой первый опыт, из которого я понял, что в Android Studio можно работать с C++ кодом( классами ).В проекте YOLO использовался TensorFlow, написанный на Python. Изучая материал дальше я создал простую модель без помощи TensorFlow на Python.
Вопрос заключается в том, каким образом можно данный документ можно внедрить в Android Studio? Чтобы дальше с ним работать.
Я заранее прошу прощения, если я во многих терминах ошибся, но мое понимание на стадии "старта". Поэтому я хотел бы узнать как возможно это сделать? Благодарю за разъяснения,ссылки, книжки, материал для этой темы.